# When to make a class final

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, final

I know that the the `final` keyword can be used to prevent you from extending a class. My question is **When should a class be marked as final?** Should every class be marked as final except for the ones that need to be extended?

Comment: Yes.  If you are OCD, you should mark every class as final except for the ones that are intentionally made to be extended.  Not everyone has that level of OCD.  (Well, I do, but I'm probably not representative of a typical C++ developer.)

Comment: How do you know, when you write a class, that you will never want or need to extend it?  I personally would only mark a class as `final` if a had a particular reason for doing so.  Taking a step into th C# world for a moment, I think that `RSACryptoServiceProvider` in .Net might be marked as `final`, and there's no doubt a good (security) reason for that.